# Calculus of variations applied to a rotating liquid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, centrifugal-force, variational-calculus

I thought I knew how to use calculus of variations, but then I started thinking about the problem of a rotating liquid and it confused me a great deal. It would be nice to hear your thoughts on the problem.

Suppose we have a liquid in a spinning cylinder in an equilibrium (i.e. the liquid is still in the rotating frame). The name of the game is to find $h_{(r)}$, the height of the liquid as a function of the radial coordinate, under the constraint of a constant volume of the liquid.

My approach was to use the calculus of variation to find $h_{(r)}$ that makes the total energy of the system stationary. I got an answer in the form of:
$$ h_{(r)} = c_1 - c_2 r^2$$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants. If you use the Lagrangian, the answer you get is $$ h_{(r)} = c_1 + c_2 r^2$$ and the constants match the accepted solution (from the books).

My question is why does minimising the total energy fail?

EDIT: $c_2 = \frac{\omega^2}{2g}$

Comment: Since the constants are arbitrary then the signs are also arbitrary. So the two answers are equivalent.

Comment: Only c1 is arbitrary (from the multipliers), while c2 is defined by the parameters. Actually, even c1 is determined by the volume of the liquid, once you calculate the multiplier.

Comment: Maybe you simply forgot a sign somwhere? Hard to say what's the mistake if you do not show your work.

Comment: I didnt, and it makes sense that the results are different, because a lagrangian is: L = KE - PE but total energy: TE = KE + PE. (and the derivation is quite lenghty)

Comment: What is the book?

Comment: Classical Mechanics by Berkshire and Kibble